# What happens when a wire is conneceted to a plug point directly?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, short-circuits

I did it in my school lab and at first nothing happened. Then I jiggled around, sparks flew out with a small explosive sound. It was really cool. The wire ends got burnt and the holes of the plug point were charred black. But what exactly happened?

---

*This is a foolish, dangerous experiment - certainly not cool. Do not repeat this experiment or play with electricity.*

Comment: There are too much current flowing across your cable.
Someone must have a resistance component.

Comment: You had a lucky escape...

Comment: What would have happened had I been unlucky? @RobJeffries

Comment: Use your imagination.

Comment: You just lost the Darwin Awards Contest. Good for you!

Comment: What happened is you did something incredibly stupid.

Comment: If you did this in the US or Japan, think of yourself as lucky. They have sensible mains outlet voltages there 115V: in Europe or here in Australia we have 240V mains: it's often almost impossible to resuscitate someone after a 240V mains shock by CPR alone and without a defibrillator. EITHER can be lethal, but you might well not have gotten away with your experiment outside the US or Japan.

Comment: It was in India. The wire was insulated. I had no idea this could happen :o. What if the current was DC, though?

Answer (score 2):

The live found a route to earth, discharging it's energy on whatever load was connected between live and earth, and then luckily the RCD cut off the supply before you cooked yourself.